# Not able to ssh localhost in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, localhost

Not able to ssh localhost in ubuntu 14.04. Tried with ip also :

```
ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ ssh ashish@localhost
Permission denied (publickey).
ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ ssh ashish@172.19.24.36
Permission denied (publickey).
ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$
```

Comment: ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ cat /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.1.1 ashishk 172.19.24.36 ashishk.example.com ashishk 172.19.24.36 ashishk # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ ping ashishk.example.com PING ashishk.example.com (172.19.24.36) 56(84) bytes of data. ^C--- ashishk.example.com ping statistics ---11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10079ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's strange , this should be the kind of output:
$ ssh eug3n10@localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

if u have the port closed ( default ) of course....
check your  /var/log/auth.log for anykind of analysis this is the start...

Comment: ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ashishk
172.19.24.36    ashishk.example.com ashishk
172.19.24.36 ashishk
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ ping ashishk.example.com
PING ashishk.example.com (172.19.24.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C--- ashishk.example.com ping statistics ---11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10079ms

Comment: @AshishKarpe if you have additional information then please edit your question and add it there rather than as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your computer does not have a private key to authenticate ssh and sshd config is set to use keys and password authentication is disabled, read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys for more info. you will need both private and public key to authenticate from local computer, if the firewall is set you may need to check that too. Check the port whether it is configured for default port 22 or some other port is used.
the config file for sshd is /etc/ssh/sshd-config, you can check the keys in ~/.ssh

Answer (score 0):

ok Ads is right , this definitely a "user-related error" the simplest thing to do is create another user with your same privileges and try again to SSH agin 
(priv-crypto key is to be automatically generated btw, not like in Cisco devices, it's strange what happens)